# MLFlow Model Registry ENDPOINT_NOT_FOUND: No API found for ERROR

Tags: azure, databricks, mlflow

I'm currently using MLFlow in Azure Databricks and trying to load a model from the Model Registry. Currently referencing the version, but will want to reference the stage 'Production' (I get the same error when referencing the stage as well)

I keep encountering an error:

```
ENDPOINT_NOT_FOUND: No API found for 'POST /mlflow/model-versions/get-download-uri'
```

My artifacts are stored in the dbfs filestore.

I have not been able to identify why this is happening.

Code:

```
from mlflow.tracking.client import MlflowClient
from mlflow.entities.model_registry.model_version_status import ModelVersionStatus

import mlflow.pyfunc

model_name = "model_name"

model_version_uri = "models:/{model_name}/4".format(model_name=model_name)

print("Loading registered model version from URI: '{model_uri}'".format(model_uri=model_version_uri))
model_version_4 = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_version_uri)

model_production_uri = "models:/{model_name}/production".format(model_name=model_name)

print("Loading registered model version from URI: '{model_uri}'".format(model_uri=model_production_uri))
model_production = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_production_uri)
```

Comment: what version of mlflow & databricks runtime are you using?

Comment: Thanks Alex - as soon as I saw your comment I knew what the problem was.  I’m running sparknlp that requires an older run time version 6.4 ML, this installs Mlflow 1.5. Running with Mlflow 1.12 in an updated DataBricks runtime works perfectly.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction